# How to pre warm / pre cache a Trusted Web Activity

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity

I'm currently using the TwaLauncher class to launch a Trusted Web Activity from my app using code like the following:

```
        val launcher = TwaLauncher(context)
        launcher.launch(Uri.parse(URL))
```

This launches a TWA from within a broader native app.

However the performance is a little slow, i'm seeing a lot of information about pre warming / pre caching with Chrome Custom Tabs (which TWA is based on) but no documentation or information on how too achieve this with TwaLauncher.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to split connecting to the service and launching the Trusted Web Activity when using the TwaLauncher.

One alternative would be to create your own version of the TwaLauncher and modify it so that those 2 steps are split.